# How can i post data from a select menu populated from database in to a table?

Tags: php, html

My php form here i made a drop down menu populated from a database...

```
<?php 
include("mysql_connect.php") 
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form-style.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="form_result.php" method="post">

    <select name="cpu">
        <?php 
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cpus");
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value=" . $row['CpuID'] . ">".$row['CpuManufacturer']." ".$row['CpuName']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Here i tried to post the selected options from the drop down menu, but the results were just showing the ID number of the database table so i tried to make a function that would echo the Name of the product for that specific ID, but it didn't work...

```
<?php
include("mysql_connect.php");

function select_cpu() {
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cpus WHERE CpuID=$cpu");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "{$row['CpuManufacturer']} {$row['CpuName']}";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $cpu = $_POST['cpu'];

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>You have selected:</th><tr>";
            echo "
            <tr><td hidden>".$cpu."</td><td>".select_cpu()."</td></tr>
            ";
        }
        echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `select_cpu` function, you should return the string instead of echoing it:

```
function select_cpu() {
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cpus WHERE CpuID=$cpu");
    $str = "";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $str .= "{$row['CpuManufacturer']} {$row['CpuName']}";
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I got this message:   "Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\select_value.php on line 5
"

Comment: @MelihGokcel You have to pass the `$conn` variable to the `select_cpu` function. You should change its definition to `function select_cpu($conn) {` and pass the variable when calling it: `select_cpu($conn)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me from having cancer :D

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet was almost right, but if you viewed the source you'd notice the `<option>` code was wrong. This is because you're mistaking the double quotes shown in HTML with what PHP sees. To output a double quote in a PHP echo, either escape it (`$something = "a double quote: \""`) or wrap it in single quotes instead (`$something = 'a double quote: "'`).

Try changing this line:

```
echo "<option value=" . $row['CpuID'] . ">".$row['CpuManufacturer']." ".$row['CpuName']."</option>";
```

to this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['CpuID'] . '">' . $row['CpuManufacturer'] . $row['CpuName'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: How do i make a space in between . $row['CpuManufacturer'] and $row['CpuName'] .  ?